# sandwich pattern in javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, aop

Apologize if the title of the question is misleading. Actually I am looking for the javascript equivalent of the following python code:

```
## python code
def call_with_context(fn, *args):
  ## code to create context, e.g. profiling, db.connect, or drawing context store stack
  fn(*args)
  ## code to close context
```

This implements the similiar functionality as the "with statement" in python, which implements the aspect-oriented paradigm.

So my question is what is the javascript way of doing such things? I have seen some code using Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1) to do so, but I don't know if this is a common pattern in javascript, or there are better patterns supported in javascript (e.g. by closure) so ppl don't really do that. Pls also correct me if I am using the wrong keywords, because I really dont know how to refer to my problem with a better name than sandwich.

EDT 1: And I appreciate if someone can explain how to return the result of fn(*args) from inside the wrapper call_with_context. thanks!

Comment: I think the question might be a little misguided.  Although there is some AOP done is Javascript, it's not that common.  With first-class functions, and everything dynamic, it's often so easy to overwrite a function with a decorated version that there's no real reason to introduce any substantial AOP tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more typical JS way of doing this might be to decorate the function.  So if you wanted to wrap your function in something that logged timing, you might create a function like this (off the top of my head):

```
var createTimer = function(fn) {
    return function() {
        var start = new Date();
        var result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("Took " + (new Date() - start) + " ms.");
        return result;
    }
};

var test = function(a, b, c) {
    return a * b + c;
}

test = createTimer(test);

console.log(test(3, 4, 5));

// Took 0 ms.
// 17
```

The main point is that you might not call something like this:

```
runTimerAround(test, 3, 4, 5);
```

although that could also be done in JS, it is, I believe less common than overwriting the functions directly.

Comment: Yes, it is more like an annotation solution in python. : )

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to call a method with specific context.

In js, you would typically do...

```
function someFunction( fn, context ) {
   fn.call( context );
}

var Button = {
   isClicked: false
};
someFunction(function () {
   // this === Button
   this.isClicked = true;
}, Button );
```

now the `this` keyword inside of `fn` will represent the context passed into the method `someFunction`. This sort of pattern is done quite often. Especially with the callbacks.

Comment: Thank, you @Trevor.  So even if fn is a method associated another object, like "console.log", the call of fn "fn.call" will still be on the correct "this" object. Is my understanding right? Or it is illegal to pass bound method around in js?

Comment: In my example, if you used console as the context, a property of `isClicked:true` would be added to the console object.

Comment: The method you pass in will go in as what is already bound to if you omit passing in context. You can pass in any method you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what about the return value if I want to return the fn.call result from inside someFunction, like directly via "return fn.call(context);" ?

Comment: That return value is whatever `fn` returns. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
// javascript code
function call_with_context(fn) {
  // code to create context, e.g. profiling, db.connect, or drawing context store stack
  var r = fn.call(Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1)); // remove first arg - fn 
  //code to close context 
  return r; 
}
```

so you will be able to do this:

```
call_with_context(myfun,1,2,3);
```

that will end up in call

```
myfun(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess by "arguments.slice" you mean "Array.prototype.slice.call" as arguments is not really an array in js? And when I tried the code in firefox, it always returns None as the result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution after some search. Hope it is helpful to others.

```
function call_with_context(fn) {
  // some beginning code
  console.log('begin');

  r = fn.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

  // some ending code
  console.log('end');

  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After having carefully read through every post/comment, I think the OP is
looking for `[javascript]` and `[method-modification]`. And answering right
away the OP's question about terminology, altering closed functionality in
JavaScript has nothing to do with *Aspect-oriented Programming* unless an
implementation that claims to be *AO* provides abstraction and code-reuse
levels for at least *Aspect*, *Advice* and *Pointcut*.

[As it already has been commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11371993/2627243)
by [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet), everything
else can be done by just (manually) wrapping functionality into one another. Here
again, I wouldn't go that far and calling it *function-composition*. In order to
qualify for that, there should be at least some tool-sets for it, as they already
exist with various implementations of `compose` and/or `curry` methods/patterns.

For what the OP is going to achieve there are a whole bunch of `before`, `after`
`around` / `wrap` solutions, mostly unfortunately mentioning *AO(P)*, and in too
many cases not taking care of the *context* or `target` which is essential and
also has been ask for by the OP.

The example I do provide uses a prototypal implementation of `Function.around`.
Because JavaScript already features a standardized `bind`, I'm firmly convinced
that `Function.prototype` is the right place as well for some other *method-modifiers*
like    `before`,
    `after`,
    `around`,
    `afterThrowing`
and    `afterFinally`.

code base that will support the afterwards following example:

```
(function (Function) {
  var
    isFunction = function (type) {
      return (
           (typeof type == "function")
        && (typeof type.call == "function")
        && (typeof type.apply == "function")
      );
    },
    getSanitizedTarget = function (target) {
      return ((target != null) && target) || null;
    }
  ;
  Function.prototype.around = function (handler, target) { // [around]
    target  = getSanitizedTarget(target);

    var proceed = this;
    return (isFunction(handler) && isFunction(proceed) && function () {

      return handler.call(target, proceed, handler, arguments);

    }) || proceed;
  };
}(Function));
```

example code, altering a given closed function by additionally provided behavior before and after it and also providing it's *context*.

```
var loggingDelegate = function () { // closed code that can not be changed for any reason.

  this.log.apply(this, arguments);
};


loggingDelegate.call(console, "log", "some", "arguments");


var interceptedLoggingDelegate = loggingDelegate.around(function (proceed, interceptor, args) {

  // everything that needs to be done before proceeding with the intercepted functionality.


  // [this] in this example refers to [console], the second argument of the [around] modifier.

  this.log("proceed:", proceed);         // the original functionality  - here [loggingDelegate].
  this.log("interceptor:", interceptor); // the modifying functionality - [around]s 1st argument.
  this.log("args:", args);               // the arguments that get passed around.


  proceed.apply(this, args);
  // or:
  //return proceed.apply(this, args);
  // or:
  //var result = proceed.apply(this, args);


  // everything that still needs to be done after invoking the intercepted functionality.

  // if necessary:
  //return result;

}, console); // [console] has to be provided as target to the modified [loggingDelegate].


interceptedLoggingDelegate("intercept", "and", "log", "some", "arguments");
```