# Is there a way to wrap try catch block to necessary function in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have many functions that need to use transaction when save or update data into database.

```
public function saveMultiple($param1, $param2)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        // save into table 1
        // save into table 2
        DB::commit();
        return true;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Instead of writing try catch block to every function, Is there a way to separate try catch block as new function and want to inject database save/update code into that function. I'm not sure it is possible or not.
Similar like this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911700/is-there-a-way-to-inject-a-try-catch-inside-a-function) but, it is for javascript. I have no idea it can implement in laravel or not because I don't have much experience with laravel. I appreciate for any advice.

Following is what I tried.
Now, I have created new class file call DBaccess.php and create a common function for try catch. The reason why I created new class because I want to access this try catch common function from different classes.

```
<?php

namespace Test\Libraries\StandardLibraries;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

Class DBaccess{

    public function transactionWrapper($action)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $action;

            DB::commit();
            $result = true;
        }
        catch (\Throwable $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::channel('debuglog')->debug($e->getMessage(). ' in file '.__FILE__.' at line '.__LINE__.' within the class '.get_class());
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And then, instantiate that DBaccess class and try to inject function that need to save/update/delete data into database as shown in below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Test\Libraries\StandardLibraries\DBaccess;
use App\Models\Approver;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\ApproverRepositoryInterface;

class ApproverRepository implements ApproverRepositoryInterface 
{
    public function saveMultiple($param1, $param2)
    {
        // object injection way
        $db = new DBaccess;
        $all = $db->transactionWrapper($this->newSaveApplicantAndApprover($param1, $param2));
        return $all;
    }

    public function newSaveApplicantAndApprover($param1, $param2)
    {
        Approver::insert($param1);
        User::insert($param1, $param2);
    }
}
```

Inside of `saveMultiple()` method, I instantiate DBaccess class and try to inject `newSaveApplicantAndApprover()` method(this is the real data saving method) into `transactionWrapper()` method.

But, it doesn't work correctly becoz if something wrong in `newSaveApplicantAndApprover()` method, data is not roll back correctly.

Comment: You can write a function to do whatever you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @miken32 now, I updated my question.

Comment: Well you still need to start your transaction and catch any errors in the function or somewhere,