# Is there any way to intercept Angular core methods to do some AOP stuff?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, aop

I'm working with Angular 12. I would like to know if it is possible to intercept a core method call such as `createComponent()` from `ViewContainerRef` under `@angular/core`, to be able to do some AOP stuff.

Comment: did you try aspectjs?

Comment: No, I will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: basically proxy api is used for such stuff, as an example you can see here :- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/javascript-how-to-intercept-function-and-method-calls-b9fd6507ff02.

Comment: _Method Modification_ (function wrapping) is as far away from the concept of AOP as is referring to the usage of just functions as _Functional Programming_. [Altering closed functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911700/is-there-a-way-to-inject-a-try-catch-inside-a-function/48499699#48499699) in JavaScript has nothing to do with _Aspect-oriented Programming_ unless an implementation that claims to be _AO_ provides **abstraction and code-reuse levels** for at least _**Aspect**_, _**Advice**_ and _**Pointcut**_.

Comment: It has been a while, I forgot why I wanted to change the behavior of the function, but now when I read your comment I couldn't agree more with you, thanks for the reference and the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of [@aspectjs](https://github.com/NicolasThierion/aspectjs), a library I recently created to to AOP for node and browser.
It cannot be used to enhance existing code from Angular, but you can enhance your own methods (or classes, parameters, properties) with a simple annotation.
Moreover, it should play nice with Angular decorators; Please tell me if it can fit your needs.