# Javascript console output before and after method call with AOP

Tags: javascript, methods, aop, function-composition, method-modifier

I would like to measure the computing time of methods.

A nice way is ([How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)) with  `console.time('Function #1');` and     `console.timeEnd('Function #1');`

My idea is to add these console outputs on lifecycle-methods. In this case using SAPUI5 like `createContent:funtion(){};` methods.

This should be possible with AOP using `before()` and `after()` to runt the time counting.

Which AOP framework would you suggest and how to implement it with the need of modifying the identification string *"Function #1"* automatically?

Comment: Regarding the `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is no need for aspects in Javascript since you can change any function of any object at any time. JavaScript prototypes allows you to manipulate method implementations of all instances of an object at runtime. Here are two approaches for what you plan.

You could use a generic wrapper function:

```
var measureId = 0;
var fnMeasureFunction = function(fnToMeasure) {
  console.time('measure'+ measureId);
  fnToMeasure();
  console.timeEnd('measure'+ measureId);
  measureId++;
}
```

Admittedly that requires you to change your actual code...

For static functions or functions that belong to a prototype you could also do sth. like this from the outside without the need of any change to your existing code:

```
// any static function
var measureId = 0;
var fnOriginalFunction = sap.ui.core.mvc.JSViewRenderer.render;
sap.ui.core.mvc.JSViewRenderer.render = function() {
  console.time('measure'+ measureId);
  fnOriginalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
  console.timeEnd('measure'+ measureId);
  measureId++;
}

// any prototype function
var fnOriginalFunction = sap.m.Button.prototype.ontouchstart;
sap.m.Button.prototype.ontouchstart= function() {
  console.time('measure'+ measureId);
  fnOriginalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
  console.timeEnd('measure'+ measureId);
  measureId++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This should be possible with AOP using before() and after() to runt the time counting.

As it already got mentioned, one really is not in need of real *Aspect-oriented Programming*
in order to solve such tasks in JavaScript. But this language might deserve some more standardized
*method-modifiers* in addition to the already existing `bind` method.

Please check back with my 2 most recent posts on this matter:

- [sandwich pattern in javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27649488/2627243)
- [Can you alter a Javascript function after declaring it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27533537/2627243)

> ... and how to implement it with the need of modifying the identification string "Function #1" automatically?

One does not need to since the console's `time` / `timeEnd` functionality only has to have
identical entry and exit points for measuring time (like the start/stop trigger of a stopwatch).
So one gets along with exactly the reference of the function/method one is currently running/measuring.

In order to solve the given task I will suggest `around` only instead of both `before` and
`after` for the former generates less overhead. The next code block exemplarily shows a
possible prototypal implementation. It also is the base for the afterwards following example
that finally might solve the OP's task.

```
(function (Function) {
  var
    isFunction = function (type) {
      return (
           (typeof type == "function")
        && (typeof type.call == "function")
        && (typeof type.apply == "function")
      );
    },
    getSanitizedTarget = function (target) {
      return ((target != null) && target) || null;
    }
  ;
  Function.prototype.around = function (handler, target) { // [around]
    target  = getSanitizedTarget(target);

    var proceed = this;
    return (isFunction(handler) && isFunction(proceed) && function () {

      return handler.call(target, proceed, handler, arguments);

    }) || proceed;
  };
}(Function));
```

The next example takes into account that *method-modification* essentially relies on
functionality that is bound to an object. It is not just function wrapping. In order
to not loose the *context* a method is operating on, *context* has to be delegated /
passed around as `target` throughout all operations.

For this the example does not modify `calculate` since it is not bound to an object
but it modifies `trigger` instead.

```js
var testObject = {

  calculate: function (hugeInteger) {
    var
      i = hugeInteger,
      k = 0
    ;
    while (i--) {
      k++;
    }
    return k;
  },
  trigger: function (hugeInteger) {
    this.result = this.calculate(hugeInteger);
  },
  result: -1
};

console.log("testObject.result : ", testObject.result);

console.log("testObject.trigger(Math.pow(2, 26)) : ", testObject.trigger(Math.pow(2, 26))); // takes some time.
console.log("testObject.result : ", testObject.result);

console.log("testObject.someTrigger(0) : ", testObject.trigger(0)); // logs immediately after.
console.log("testObject.result : ", testObject.result);


testObject.trigger = testObject.trigger.around(function (proceed, interceptor, args) {

  // before:
  console.time(proceed);

  // proceed:
  proceed.apply(this, args);

  // after:
  console.timeEnd(proceed);

}, testObject); // omitting the 2nd argument - the [target] object - might break code that did work before.


console.log("testObject.trigger(Math.pow(2, 26)) : ", testObject.trigger(Math.pow(2, 26)));
console.log("testObject.result : ", testObject.result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  (function (Function) {
    var
      isFunction = function (type) {
        return (
             (typeof type == "function")
          && (typeof type.call == "function")
          && (typeof type.apply == "function")
        );
      },
      getSanitizedTarget = function (target) {
        return ((target != null) && target) || null;
      }
    ;
    Function.prototype.around = function (handler, target) { // [around]
      target  = getSanitizedTarget(target);

      var proceed = this;
      return (isFunction(handler) && isFunction(proceed) && function () {

        return handler.call(target, proceed, handler, arguments);

      }) || proceed;
    };
  }(Function));
</script>
```